# Is there any way to choose a video from photo roll in windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I want to create a windows phone 8 app that allows the user to view, mark (draw lines over), and slow down/speed up videos on their phone.  I'm trying to figure out how to "load" a video from the user's photo roll so they can perform the above functions on that video.

From what I can tell from my research so far it's impossible to "pick" a video file from the user's photo roll.  Here are the two things I have tried:

1. the "PhotoChooserTask" - only allows image files
2. the "FileOpenPicker" class -  doesn't currently work on WP8  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpdevelop/thread/7e4492dc-d8f3-4dc5-8055-625352aaa8b6

I am very surprised something as simple as this isn't currently achievable with WP8 SDK.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/dd904198.aspx Try this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is still no way, how choose video from MediaLibrary and use it in your app. You can only play your own video, or some video stream from the Internet.

Comment: that is sad.  Basically blows my app idea out of the water, super lame.